# How to automate changing the project settings in Visual Studio 2005 and later

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

i have a visual studio 2005/2010 projects and each of these project is made up of 20 projects and all these projects are managed by a single solution file(.sln)

now if i had to change any compiler or linker settings, i have to manually do it for all the 20 projects, is there anyway this can be automated using a script or Addin or any other method.

appreciate your time and attention

Comment: Just select all the projects first so you only have to make the change once :)

Comment: @HansPassant Oh my gosh, I am really feeling kinda awkward now after my answer below... yeah, this would really be much more simpler :)

Comment: Yeah, I posted it as a comment intentionally.  Don't delete your answer, somebody might well find it to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are property sheets. Visual Studio already has a mechanism that almost enables you to do everything you are asking for.

A property sheet (`*.props`) basically is a separate settings file that you can attach to as much projects that you like, and all the configured properties are applied to these projects. Think of it as if the projects are "inheriting" from another configuration - and that's exactly what's happening.

Let's say you have a base configuration of include directories, linker directories, library includes, preprocessor defines and so forth, and you know that each project uses them in each configuration (Debug, Release, ...). You can create one property sheet `defaults.props` and apply it to all your 20 projects. Then, if you require a change, just edit the property sheet file, and all the changes will be reflected to all 20 projects.

To create property sheets, click on `View -> Property Manager` (not to be confused with the "Property Window"!). A window should pop up where you can see all your projects with all their configurations. Now right click on any of your projects and select `Add New Property Sheet`, type in a name and save it somewhere. This will create a `.props` file and adds it to all the configurations of your single project. You can then edit this property sheet from this window like it was a real project (right click on the property sheet and select `Properties`).

After you have created your property sheet you can go ahead and right click on the other 19 projects and do a `Add Existing Property Sheet`. You have to do this once for all your projects, sure, but after that your property sheet enables you to change the settings for all projects at once.

Also noteworthy is that you can have multiple property sheets applied to one project. If you do so, they are being applied in order (you can reorder them if you like) so you are able to configure your projects in more detail. For instance, you could have this `default.props` that applies to *everything*, and then you could have a `default_debug.props` that is only intended for Debug configurations. The first one sets up all your include and library directories, the second one does library specifications and defines specific for Debug configs.

One last important note: If you have set some properties directly in your project (which you obviously have), it will automatically override any settings you have specified in your property sheet. You can see this if a setting in your project has a **bold** value. If you want to revert it to the property sheet value, clear the setting and select the `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` from the drop down menu of the setting. Include- and Linker-Directories are a special case, in which you will ALWAYS inherit everything specified in the property sheet unless explicitly disabled.

EDIT: I am not quite sure about VS2005/VS2008, and iirc they have the same principle with a `*.vsprops` file, but this may be incompatible with the `*.props` files from VS2010+